# Permission denied writing in directories with g+w mode on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

On ubuntu 10.04.4 server, I did this:

```
sudo mkdir -p /data/somedir
sudo chown -R www-data.www-data /data/somedir
sudo chmod -R g+w /data/somedir
sudo usermod -a -G www-data john ##john is current login user.
```

. With these operations done, I suppose to have write permission in `/data/somedir`. But when I did this:

```
echo "123" > /data/somedir/123
```

, I got:

```
-bash: /data/somedir/123: Permission denied
```

The ls -l output:

```
$ ls -l /data/
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 2012-04-24 22:30 somedir
```

Question is: why? Is there something I still need to do after that?

Comment: Could you show us the output of `ls -al /data/somedir`?

Comment: What does `id` tell you about your login identity?  Is `www-data` listed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changes made with `usermod` only take effect on following logins; your existing login session does not yet have the `www-data` group, as you can verify with `id`.  It is not easy to alter the identity of running processes (`newgrp` *might* work); the easiest way to deal is to log out and back in.